# Javascript - get width of child within some relative set to display:none

Tags: javascript

I have some list items that are hidden because of a hidden grandparent (or greater relative). I can recurse through the relatives and set each one to display:block;position:absolute;left:999em; then take the child width or shoudl I just offer an option argument in the getwidth function to take the hidden relative if one exists?

Or does anybody have a more elegant solution? This is in javascript no libraries.

Comment: How about a little more context? I'm tempted to say that things that can't be seen take up no horizontal space and are zero pixels wide (not my DV).

Comment: <div style="display:none">.....<ul><li>NEED THE HEIGHT/WIDTH OF THIS WHEN ITS VISIBLE</li></ul>.....</div>

Comment: Ah context: On a hover for example a submenu would be revealed at which point it would gain width/height. In my case though Im calculating widths where the 'hiding' relative might be unknown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure at this, but I've read somewhere (I think it was w3schools) that elements that are display="hidden" can be calculated upon (width/height), where as elements that are display="none" cannot.

So one solution could be to use display="hidden" instead of none?

But when do you want to get the width/height? When the element is hidden or visible?

- Molle